# Sending out email with PHPMailer from GoDaddy Share Hosting is SLOW - 1min to 3 mins

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've a website hosted with GoDaddy Share Hosting and my phpmailer is very slow compared to other business services while sending emails, takes around 1 to 3 minutes...

Email content is less than 300 words, and follow by

```
$this->SendEmail(EMAIL_FROM, $member_email, admin@example.com, $subject, $message, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have had this issue along with many.

A possible solution could be to use PHPMailer and Gmail

```
<?php

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
$mail->DKIM_domain = '127.0.0.1';
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host        = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port        = 465;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username    = "arjun@arjunphp.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password    = "password";
$mail->SMTPSecure  = 'ssl';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('no-reply@arjunphp.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('arjunphp@gmail.com', 'Arjun');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

[Source](https://arjunphp.com/sending-emails-with-phpmailer-using-godaddy-smtp-email/)

[Download PHPMailer](http://gitub.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is much appreciated. I'm going to try that out now.Btw, you've mentioned "Gmail" in your text, could you please make it clear that which part of the code define that? is it the port number using 465?

Comment: Please check the source link for more information. Basically its GoDaddy throttling and filtering emails to prevent spam and to make more sales on their higher plans.

Comment: Hi. What is the "Username"? Is it the email account I created in GoDaddy's Workspace Control Center?

Answer (score -2):

Get a real host. Sorry to be pessimistic, but nothing much gets solved when labouring under GoDaddy shared hosting :(

To be more helpful try looking into third party SMTP providers like Elastic Email (https://elasticemail.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try troubleshooting first. Though you're right, VPS is way better. However, because of Company's requirements, (email accounts, easily manageable cpanel), I have no choice. :(

Comment: I understand, but do check out Elastic Email. You company will probably like the stats, admin panel, etc etc. It has an easily integratable php class.

Comment: Bear in mind you can't use other SMTP providers from GoDaddy - they block all outbound SMTP - you can work around that by using a mail provider that provides an HTTP sending interface. Gandi.net has some good options for VPS with control panels and mail accounts/routing, and they also have the advantage of not being bottom-of-the-barrel junk.

Comment: Thanks @mayersdesign as well.

Comment: It's not an SMTP provider as such, its more an API connected total replacement for the mail system on GoDaddy